# Flutter LatLng no permite asignar parametros

Tags: flutter

Estoy trabajando con `LatLng` en ***flutter***, recibo dos parámetros tipo `double` a una clase, y quiero asignarlos a `LatLng` y no me lo permite, el error es:

> Only Static members can be accessed in initializers

La clase es de tipo `StateFulWidget`. Y los asigno de la siguiente manera:

```
class GoogleMaps extends StatefulWidget {

  final double x,y;
  GoogleMaps(this.x , this.y );
  LatLng location = new LatLng(x , y);
```

Obviamente el codigo sigue, pero para abreviar solamente copie el problema.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la clase `State` de tu `GoogleMaps` widget, debes instanciar el atributo location, de la siguiente manera:

```dart
class _GoogleMaps extends State<GoogleMaps> {

 LatLng location;

 @override
  void initState() {
    location = new LatLng(widget.x , widget.y);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Tu clase `GoogleMaps` quedaría así:

```dart
class GoogleMaps extends StatefulWidget {

  final double x,y;
  GoogleMaps(this.x , this.y );
```